# Nested For Each statements

Tags: vba, excel

So what I'm trying to do is loop through two columns, if the cell in column 1 has a value in it, find that value on another sheet, and take that entire row, and paste it on another sheet, and then take the value in column two's cell that is adjacent to the column 1 value, and paste the row onto the same sheet.

So if Column 1 in "Common Build" is equal to 12345, it will search the "S&OP Final Sheet" for 12345, take that entire row, paste it into "Common Build Projects," go to the second column in "Common build" (=12346) search for those values, and then paste that row into the "Common Build Projects", and go down through column two til the next blank. The goal is that the user can enter in a list with the projects and have it read it based off that. It would be formatted the same way every time so that won't be an issue. I left a blank in between each so that it would be able to exit to go to the next line.

The code runs fine, I just can't get it to pull values. I've added watches and nothing has happened. The matching list is several thousand lines long so I can't go through it all til it matches.

The list is formatted as such (code was the only way it would let me show it, sorry if this isn't the proper format)

```
CB project Individual Project
12335      12336
blank      12337
blank      12338
blank      12339

12345      12346
blank      12347
blank      12348
blank      12349
```

Here is my current code:

```
Sub CommonBuilds()
Sheets("Common Build").Select
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim y As String
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
For Each c In Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
    y = Cells(c.row, 1).value
    If y <> "" Then
        Sheets("S&OP Final").Select
        lastrow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        For Each c2 In Range("E2:E" & lastrow2)
            If Cells(c2.row, 5).value = y Then
                Cells(c2.row, 5).EntireRow.Copy
                Sheets("Common Build Projects").Select
                With Sheets("Common Build Projects")
                    .Rows(.Cells(Sheets("Common Build Projects").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End With
            End If
        Next
        Sheets("Common Build").Select
        For Each c3 In Range("B2:B" & lastrow)
            z = Cells(c3.row, 2).value
            If z <> "" Then
            Sheets("S&OP Final").Select
                For Each c2 In Range("E2:E" & lastrow2)
                    If Cells(c2.row, 5).value = z Then
                        Cells(c2.row, 5).EntireRow.Copy
                        Sheets("Common Build Projects").Select
                        With Sheets("Common Build Projects")
                            .Rows(.Cells(Sheets("Common Build Projects").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                        End With
                    End If
                Next
            ElseIf z = "" Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: I will dare to say that this almost sounds possible with multiple combinations of `INDEX` and `MATCH` and VBA may not be needed...

Comment: I'm trying to create a macro that other people will use, otherwise I would do that

Comment: Can you clearly explain what the exact issue is your running into here?  You posted what you want to accomplish, what you have tried, but I do not know what exactly is not working with your current attempt.  It will help others to help you if you clearly state that

Comment: Then put the formula in the macro and set each cell's formula to what you need.

Comment: Install and use Smart Indenter (http://www.oaltd.co.uk/indenter/). It's free and it might make that code readable. Also use Option Explicit, and compile.

Comment: @chancea the code is quasi functional at this point. For whatever reason it stops after the first line though.

Comment: When you get to `Next c` it looks as though the "Common Build` sheet may not necessarily be selected in all cases. Therefore, your `y = Cells(c.row, 1).value` might not work as intended and so on. Also, not sure why you didn't use `y = c.value`. Qualify your cells references with a worksheet and don't bother with all the selecting business

Comment: I think I've discovered that my issue is the double loop doesn't go back to the outside loop(duh on my part) to change the value of y each time it goes to the cell. So the sheet will work properly but it won't pull values as I like. Still not sure how to get around it though.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest firstly that you read the two columns into an array.

```
dim myarray() as variant

myarray = range("A2:E" & lastrow).value2
```

Then loop through the column E values, looking for blanks:

```
n = 2
cb_project = myarray(n,1)

do while n <= lastrow
    'copy row matching cb_project

    if myarray(n,5) = "" then
        cb_project = myarray(n+1,1)
    else
        'copy row matching myarray(n,5)
    endif

    n=n+1
loop
```

Answer (score 0):

First, things like `Range("A2:A" And lastrow)` cannot work. You have to use the string concatenation operator: '`&`', like this: `Range("A2:A" & lastrow)`. You have several occurences of this.
Second, please indent your code ! Properly indented code is sooo much easier to read and maintain !

Comment: I tried indenting it, I have it indented in VBA and the formatting here won't display it. Sorry!

Comment: Ok, much better now !

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the line

```
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
```

finds the last row *in column 1*. Unfortunately, if I understand the logic correctly, you want (need) the last row in column 2 - since the list of values in column 2 goes further than the list in column 1 (or at least that is my interpretation of what you need in

```
        For Each c3 In Range("B2:B" & lastrow)
```

In other words - for the sample you gave, you will only look for the first line of the second project (`12346`), and not look for any further matches. Could that be your problem?

Solution would be to add a line

```
        lastBrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
```

and change the For loop to

```
        For Each c3 In Range("B2:B" & lastBrow)
```

Comment: I had found that, which is a very good point, but I think the issue now is to get it to loop through the "S&OP final" sheet with looped values. When I run it with the proper lastrow it will loop just fine but y does not change because it's in the outside loop. Not really sure of a work around. Thanks though!